# User Guide or User's Guide (or something else)?

Tags: terminology

Since almost every designer/developer I know RTFM's (ahem), thought I'd ask...

When you need a reference to help you understand a tool, which term to you think of/search for?

1. User Guide
2. User's Guide
3. Users' Guide

Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User guide seems to be used far and above more frequently than either of the alternative terms. On [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=user%20guide,user%27s%20guide,users%27%20guide), its search frequency is given as 66, while the frequency for both other terms is 4 each.

That's further reflected on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_guide) and Wiktionary, where "user guide" is the main entry title and "user's guide" is presented as an alternative.

That said, take "user manual" into consideration, too. Based on Google Trends, it's used even more frequently than "user guide."